# How to get gRPC response limit

Tags: go, grpc

I have Go gRPC endpoint that returns an array of some items. I want to limit the number of items in response to make fit the maximum that gRPC allows to send.

My idea is to get the maximum in handler func, divide it by item size and voilà. But how can I get response max size?

I don't want to set max response size to make my class independent of grpc instantiation.

---

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "main/api"
    "main/router"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:138080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()

    r := router.New()

    api.RegisterTestGenerateServiceServer(grpcServer, r)

    err = grpcServer.Serve(l)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to run server: %v", err)
    }
}
```

---

**router.go**

```golang
package router

import (
    "context"
    "main/api"
    "main/model"
    "unsafe"
)

type router struct {
}

func New() *router {
    return &router{}
}

func (r *router) TestCall(context.Context, *api.TestCallRequest) (*api.TestCallResponse, error) {
    items := somewhere.GetItems()
    apiItems := transform.ToAPIItems(items)
    
    itemSize := unsafe.Sizeof(model.Item{})
    
    responseSize := someWonderFuncGetGrpcResponseMaxSize()
    
    NItems := responseSize / itemSize

    return &api.TestCallResponse{
        Items: apiItems[:NItems],
    }, nil
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's good design to couple the behaviour of a method to the properties of the channel, whether you do this explicitly or implicitly. If you expect to be returning a large number of items, consider using a [server-streaming RPC](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/#server-streaming-rpc).

Comment: I agree with you in general. But sometimes we have to do a bad things to make legacy code work. The question still is "can we know what is gRPC response limit?"

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `context.Context` received by the call? I suspect it might divulge the `CallOption`s if prodded in the right way. Perhaps not in a very supported way, but you hinted you were willing to do bad things, so... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating [grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(s int)](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#MaxCallSendMsgSize) on your client to enable your client send larger message.
This worked for me, as example:

```
func main() {
    // create connection
    opts := []grpc.DialOption{
        // grpc.WithInsecure(),
        grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(math.MaxInt32)), // uncomment for large amount of data returned
    }
    cc, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:9089", opts...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to dial: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer cc.Close()

    client := pb.NewGrpcServiceClient(cc)
    data, err := client.GetDataFromGRPCService()
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question I don't want to set limit as my code is a part of a bigger service. I need to GET the value instead of setting it